# Get 2 digit without round in postgresql or SQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I Need to take 2 digit from fraction part without round.

SELECT 110.10666

## OUTPUT WILL BE

110.10

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your participation. However, the community does expect a certain quality in the questions posted. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_. Currently your question is contradicting and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). I.e, you are tagging with [tag:sql-server] (a Microsoft product) and [tag:postgresql] (a PostgresSQL product). Consider revising your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL-Server you can play with math:

> ```
> SELECT CAST(26.6689 * 100 as int) / 100.0;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 26.660000        |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b4c0e54ebd80ab752d88240c990d197d)*

On Postgres you can use [TRUNC()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-math.html) function:

> ```
> SELECT trunc(26.6689, 2);
> ```
>
> ```
> | trunc |
> | ----: |
> | 26.66 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=23d081cd8801c4b6229522df428e195a)*

Answer (score 1):

For `SQL Server` you can use `round()` with function "truncate" (last argument 1) to truncate your input to requested number of digits (second argument of `round()`)

> Arguments
>
> *numeric_expression*
>
> Is an expression of the exact numeric or
>   approximate numeric data type category, except for the bit data type.
>
> *length*
>
> Is the precision to which numeric_expression is to be rounded.
>   length must be an expression of type tinyint, smallint, or int. When
>   length is a positive number, numeric_expression is rounded to the
>   number of decimal positions specified by length. When length is a
>   negative number, numeric_expression is rounded on the left side of the
>   decimal point, as specified by length.
>
> *function*
>
> Is the type of operation to perform. function must be
>   tinyint, smallint, or int. When function is omitted or has a value of
>   0 (default), numeric_expression is rounded. When a value other than 0
>   is specified, numeric_expression is truncated.

```
SELECT round(110.10666, 2, 1);
```

Here the details of [ROUND (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

and then use `cast()` to get rid of unnecessary zeros:

```
SELECT cast(round(110.10666, 2, 1) as decimal(10,2));
```

Comment: @Lennart, your code rounds the input, i.e. the result is 110.11 and NOT 110.10 as was requested